# Content API Version for Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

can anyone tell me, if/how it is possible to update the version of the Content API in Google Apps Script. When I'm trying to enable the Content API in the Google Advanced Services Section I can only select "v2" but I would like to use "v2.1".

Kind regards
Andi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an Advanced Service in Apps Script, unfortunately you can only use the version that the Apps Script offers you when you click on `Resources - > Advanced Google Services`.

In case of Content API it is currently `v2`. Sorry for not being able to give you a more positive answer.